# EaselJs and TweenJs: Change image of Bitmap in tweening

Tags: javascript, tweenjs

I'm trying to create an animation with a flask image. I want to pour the flask, then replace the flask with an empty one, and then return the flask to its original location. The code I have right now looks like this:

```
var renderPour = function (flask, index){
  // Using a Motion Guide
  curX = flask.x;
  curY = flask.y;
  createjs.Tween.get(flask)
    .wait(2000*index)
    .to({x:100, y:90, rotation:-100}, 700, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
    .to({image:'/assets/empty_flask'+(index+1)+'.svg'}, 0)
    .to({x:curX, y:curY, rotation:0}, 700, createjs.Ease.quadOut);
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/classes/Tween.html#method_to), it says

```
Non-numeric properties will be set at the end of the specified duration.
```

So I expect the image src property to be changed. But when I run my code, the Bitmap just disappears and I have a 'invisible' Bitmap there. I know it's still there because I have an array that keeps track of all Bitmaps and it's still there, and I just can't see it. When I check the image's src value in the console, it's changed and correct.

I did some research and guessed that it's probably because the stage is not updated. Here is my update stage code:

```
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Ticker.on("tick", tick);
createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install();
function tick(event) {
  stage.update(event);
  console.log('x: ', flaskArr[1].x, 'y', flaskArr[1].y);
}
```

And I tried to run stage.update() in the console as well, but the Bitmap is still invisible.

Additionally it seems that the later half of the animation is still working, except that the Bitmap is not showing according to the log.

I'm wondering is there a correct way to replace the image in TweenJs? Or is there another way to replace the image in the middle of the animation? Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution on my own, so i'll just post it. I have to pass a new image instead of just a src string:

```
var emptImage = new Image();
emptImage.src = emptyFlaskPath(id);
createjs.Tween.get(flask)
  .wait(2000*(flask.id-1))
  .to({x:100, y:90, rotation:-100}, 700, createjs.Ease.quadOut)
  .to({image: emptImage}, 0)
  .to({x:curX, y:curY, rotation:0}, 700, createjs.Ease.quadOut);
```